# Manage iPhone Calendar event from our application

Tags: iphone, xcode, calendar, eventkit

The following is my code

```
NSLog(@"%@", thisEvent1.title); 

EKEvent *thisEvent  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];

eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

thisEvent = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];


NSDateFormatter *   dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd:HH:mm"];


NSDate * date = [[NSDate alloc] init];
date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[itsStartDate objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
[date retain];

thisEvent.startDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[itsStartDate objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
thisEvent.endDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[itsEndDate objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
thisEvent.notes = [itsNotes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
thisEvent.title = [itsTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
thisEvent.location = [itsLocation objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
// thisEvent.allDay = TRUE;
NSMutableArray *myAlarmsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

EKAlarm *alarm1 = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:-[[itsAlertOne objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] intValue]]; // 1 Hour
// EKAlarm *alarm2 = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:-86400]; // 1 Day

[myAlarmsArray addObject:alarm1];
//[myAlarmsArray addObject:alarm2];

thisEvent.alarms = myAlarmsArray;
[myAlarmsArray release];

//setting the Reuccurence rule

NSString * test1 = [itsRecurrenceFrequency objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    BOOL isRecurrenceFrequencyExists = TRUE;

EKRecurrenceFrequency  recurrenceFrequency;

if ([test1 isEqualToString: @"EKRecurrenceFrequencyDaily"]) {
    recurrenceFrequency = EKRecurrenceFrequencyDaily;
}else if([test1 isEqualToString: @"EKRecurrenceFrequencyWeekly"]){
    recurrenceFrequency = EKRecurrenceFrequencyWeekly;
}else if([test1 isEqualToString: @"EKRecurrenceFrequencyMonthly"]){
    recurrenceFrequency = EKRecurrenceFrequencyMonthly;
}else if([test1 isEqualToString: @"EKRecurrenceFrequencyYearly"]){
    recurrenceFrequency = EKRecurrenceFrequencyYearly;
}else{
    isRecurrenceFrequencyExists = FALSE;
}

    if(isRecurrenceFrequencyExists){
        EKRecurrenceRule * recurrenceRule = [[EKRecurrenceRule alloc] 

                                     initRecurrenceWithFrequency:recurrenceFrequency
                                     interval:[[itsRecurrenceInterval objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]intValue]
                                     end:nil];
        if (thisEvent.endDate != nil) {
            EKRecurrenceEnd * end = [EKRecurrenceEnd recurrenceEndWithEndDate:thisEvent.endDate];
            recurrenceRule.recurrenceEnd = end;
        }else {
            thisEvent.endDate = thisEvent.startDate;
        }

        thisEvent.recurrenceRule = recurrenceRule;
        [recurrenceRule release];

    }
[thisEvent setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
NSError *err;


[eventStore saveEvent:thisEvent span:EKSpanFutureEvents error:&err]; 
NSLog(@"%@", thisEvent.eventIdentifier);
[self.eventsList addObject:thisEvent];
```

In this code I have the Event id of my calendar event.

1. Now I want to update the event with the changes however Its not updating the previously created event.
2. Second I Need to know is it possible to capture the changes in calendar event they made in iPhone Calendar including deleting an event.
3. Can we delete the calendar event using the eventid?

Please help me if any one know the answer..  Thank you in advance.

Regards,
Dilip Rajkumar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Event can be created by this:

```
[eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err]; 
   NSString* str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", event.eventIdentifier];
[arrayofCalIDs addObject:str];
```

You can delete the event using this:

```
EKEventStore* store = [[[EKEventStore alloc] init] autorelease];
   EKEvent* event2 = [store eventWithIdentifier:[arrayofCalIDs objectAtIndex:i]];
if (event2 != nil) {  
  NSError* error = nil;
  [store removeEvent:event2 span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&error];
} 
[myPath release];

For Updating Event you cannot directly access any method as it is not available in iOS. So, you can do one thing for this. 
(1) First remove the event with eventID.
(2) Create new Event using the same information of the last deleted event.
```

Comment: It is really a good Idea Thank you very much for your help.  I have another doubt,  1. Is it possible for me to get the events created by our app and 2. If the user edits the event created by our app using iPhone calendar is it possible for us to get the modified event when we open our app.   Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello, We can do one thing here to manage the event creation. You can have one database or plist for events which take care of all the events created by your app. And for the other points I will check it out and let you know soon.

Comment: Yes its working,  however i am working on another task will continue task may be next week,  only then i will face more problem thanks for your response.  I will let you know once i complete.  Thank you once again.

Comment: AppAspect.. I started working on this issue again Now I can able to do  every thing the only problem I am having now is the method "EKEventEditViewActionDeleted" in eventEditViewController is calling thrice when I delete a event.  Kindly help me.. Thanks in advance